# Springboot internationalisation messages from spring cloud config

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

We have a spring-boot + Thymeleaf web application that shows messages in different languages. These messages are within the app as default: 
/src/main/resources/messages.properties

The app configuration loads from a spring-boot cloud config service. I wonder if would it be possible to load the messages.properties file remotely from the config server instead of using the internal one (as the app also loads the application.yml)

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046062/spring-cloud-load-message-sources-from-config-server/59073406#59073406